# AWS. Get list of Permissions for IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have some question about IAM permissions. I have IAM User. who has such minimal permissions

1) For IAM:

```
{
"Version": "2010-12-14",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:ChangePassword"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
 ]
}
```

2) For S3

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1234567890123",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

And I need to write some Api, using Java SDK, which be ablle to check if user has this minimal permissions, but on this level of access, I can not get my own permissions, policies, roles. It is possible to do so with this level of access?

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS java sdk you can get IAM permissions of yours and other IAM users. But you need to have required AWS resource permission.

For ex http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-user-policies.html

To list other user policies you should have IAM:list-user-policies.

Likewise whatever AWS resources you try to access require permissions to query the resource. Your permissions can be set directly to you in permissions or role with permissions have been assigned to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with identifying IAM user permission and I had to write an API that had to be responsible for that. So used AWS java SDK, IAM module, where such ability had already presented. I used simulatePrincipalPolicy request

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.